# POST requests to Node.js app behind nginx not getting through

Tags: node.js, nginx

POST requests to http://mysite.io:5003/GetProjects, works fine(http). But POST requests to https://mysite.io:5003/GetProjects returns 'Could not get any response' in Postman and 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' on my site at http://mysite.io/Projects. I'm using PM2 to run my backend.js and am also just running node backend.js to debug. OS is Ubuntu 16.04 in a EC2 instance, which has port 443 open.

nginx config is:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name mysite.io www.mysite.io;

  root /var/www/html/mysite-service/build;

  location / {
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: https and https both will listen on different port and you are not using nginx if you use https://example.com:5003, you need to use https://example.com only(without port if you want to use Nginx reverse proxy)

Comment: can you try by turning off `Automatically follow redirects`?

Comment: Thanks Arif figured this out by removing port :5003 on the initial request, but then proxying to 5003 in nginx..sorry I'm new to Nginx!